# R eval parse encode utf-8 uses windows 1252

Tags: r, utf-8

I have a R code file that is encoded with UTF-8. In want to use it on windows.

When I source the file (with encoding='UTF-8'); I get no error but when call the function within the file: I get an Error at the first non-ascii character. Therefore I tried:

```
eval(parse(path.to.file, encoding='UTF-8'))
```

I get the Errror: unexpected input: `40:   KL_daily <- dwd_Klima_df %>% filter(AbkÃ¼` which looks for me like instead UTF-8 Windows 1252 is used for encoding. How do I solve this coding problem.
Using non ascii characters here is important for filter to work.

Comment: Note: the same byte sequence can be interpreted differently. In your case: R read it as UTF-8, but if your console (shell or R console) uses cp1252, so the console will just misinterpret the bytes of the files. Just check that your working environment is consistent (so usually UTF-8 on all stack)

Comment: What version of R are you using?  If it is not 4.2 (which is the most recent) try it again with 4.2.

Comment: I had 4.0 - updating to 4.2 enabled the eval parse.